# WinRT Gridview DragItemsStarting event: How to find control being dragged?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working on a XAML/C# WinRT app.  The app has a Gridview with a grouped source.  I'm implementing manual drag/drop functionality on the Gridview (because MS, in their great wisdom, decided to skip that crucial functionality in grouped Gridviews).

One problem I'm facing is trying to get a reference to the control being dragged.  In the DragItemsStarting event, we have:

```
private void GVDragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
var item = e.Items.FirstOrDefault();
if (item == null)
    return;

e.Data.Properties.Add("item", item);
}
```

However, sender here is just the GridView, not the control being dragged, and e.Items[0] points to the underlying data model object, not the actual control.  Is there a way to get the actual control being dragged somewhere in the drag event chain before the drop happens?  I was thinking of peeking in the PointerPressed event, but that didn't even fire while dragging.

This seems like a no-brainer that I think I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested using the `ContainerFromItem`, it would be better to reference the GridView which fired original event in the handler:

```
private void GVDragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e) 
{ 
   GridView g = (GridView)sender;
   var draggedControl = g.ContainerFromItem(e.Items[0]);
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with the events a bit, I figured it out: One can get the control being dragged by handling the ManipulationStarting event and storing either the e.Container or e.OriginalSource in a class variable to access later in the drag events.

Comment: an even better solution is the following, which doesn't require the tracking of a variable:

var draggedControl = itemGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.Items[0])

Comment: Please combine your multiple answers into a single answer and delete the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

an even better solution is the following, which doesn't require the tracking of a variable:

```
var draggedControl = itemGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.Items[0]);
```